# Bulk delete in array by using typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I want to do bulk delete from an array using typescript.

I did it by using for loop.

```
this.versions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
this.selectedVersions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedVersions.length; i++) {
  this.versions = this.removeObjectFromArray(this.versions, this.selectedVersions[i]);
}


//removing a object from array
removeObjectFromArray(listOfdata: any, data: any) {
  let index = listOfdata.findIndex(function (o) {
    return o === data;
  })
  listOfdata.splice(index, 1);
  return listOfdata;
}
```

But I don't like to use `for loop`.so let me know how to do bulk delete in array using typescript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use array filter:

```js
var versions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var selectedVersions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

versions = versions.filter(el => !selectedVersions.includes(el));
console.log(versions);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `array.filter` and filter the contents of the arrays based on the condition

```js
let versions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
let selectedVersions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
versions = versions.filter(arrayVal => selectedVersions.indexOf(arrayVal) == -1 );
// checks for the values of selected Versions agains each value of versions and returns accordindly
console.log(versions)
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason you don't use includes instead of indexOf?

Comment: I didn't see to it really @Matt this was the first thing that stuck my small mind :p

Comment: It's fine either way. Both works. Just was curious if it was a performance thing or not.

Answer (score 2):

Use a filter

```
// will only keep elements that are not included in selectedVersions
this.versions = this.versions.filter(i => !this.selectedVersions.includes(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use indexOf, like this:

```
this.versions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
this.selectedVersions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedVersions.length; i++)  
  {  
if(this.versions.indexOf(this.selectedVersions[i])!==-1){
this.versions.splice(index, 1);
}
  }
```

Comment: Actually I don't want use for loops.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use a filter for this to preserve the original arrays:

```
let nonSelectedVersions = this.versions.filter((e) => this.selectedVersions.indexOf(e) !== -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array.filter() instead of for loop

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is the same as javascript, you can us all your knowledges from JS.

[How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-do-i-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

You can use for-of loop as well, if you TS compiler support

```
var versions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
var selectedVersions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    for ( val of  selectedVersions)  {        
       if(selectedVersions.indexOf(val)!=-1){
           versions.splice(versions.indexOf(val), 1);
       }
    }
```