# Update multiple object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I want to do bulk update to an array using typescript.

I did it by using for loop.

```js
this.versions = [{ id: 1, VersionName: 'test1' }, { id: 2, VersionName: 'test2' }, { id: 3, VersionName: 'test3' }, { id: 4, VersionName: 'test4' }];
this.selectedVersions = [{ id: 2, VersionName: 'test2' }, { id: 3, VersionName: 'test3' }];
for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedVersions.length; i++) {
  this.versions = this._configuration.updateEveryObjectsByKey(this.versions, this.selectedVersions[i], "Id");
}

updateEveryObjectsByKey(listOfdata: any, data: any, key: string) {
  listOfdata = listOfdata.map(function (item) {
    return item[key] == data[key] ? data : item;
  })
  return listOfdata;
}
```

But I don't like to use for loop. So let me know how to do bulk update to array using typescript?

Comment: What about [the question you asked 25 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913059/bulk-delete-in-array-by-using-typescript) ? It has 7 answers.

Comment: That's related with multiple delete by using findIndex or filter. But this multiple update by using map or else. So I have asked separate question .

Comment: Ok, fair enough

Comment: Your current code doesn't actually modify the original objects. Instead it will completely replace the original object with the new object from `selectedVersions`. Is this a functionality you want to keep?

Comment: @BeetleJuice Actually I don't think a much difference between update and replace !

Comment: There's a big difference between update and replace, for example you have `{ id: 0, a: 2, b: 3 }`. Update with `{ id: 0, a: 3 }` will result in `{ id: 0, a: 3, b: 3 }` while replace will result in `{ id: 0, a: 3 }`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use ES6's *Object.assign*, *array.find* and *array.map* :

```js
var versions = [{ id: 1, VersionName: 'test1' }, { id: 2, VersionName: 'test2' }, { id: 3, VersionName: 'test3' }, { id: 4, VersionName: 'test4' }];
var selectedVersions = [{ id: 2, VersionName: 'test2 update' }, { id: 3, VersionName: 'test3' }];
var key = "id";
versions = versions.map(el => {
  var found = selectedVersions.find(s => s[key] === el[key]);
  if (found) {
      el = Object.assign(el, found);
  }
  return el;
});
console.log(versions);
```

Comment: In this solution, the key used to compare is hardcoded to `id` whereas the OP sets it dynamically in the current code.

Comment: @BeetleJuice What is exactly am typing. I want to it by using key instead of id. because I would use this method as a common method. :)

Comment: So I think I need to change `s.id === el.id` to `s[key] === el[key]`??

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution to a potentially complex problem.

```
           $scope.model.ticketsArr.forEach(function (Ticket) {
                if (Ticket.AppointmentType == 'CRASH_TECH_SUPPORT') {
                    Ticket.AppointmentType = '360_SUPPORT'

                }
            });
```